# Detectar si en una tabla existen valores duplicados para una columna o combinación de columnas

Tags: sql-server

Necesito hacer una `query` que me permita saber que valores o cuantos valores (total) existen duplicados en mi tabla para cierta columna.

Comment: me alegra que encontraras una solución a tu problema. Para futuras publicaciones, por favor añade más información: ¿qué estructura tienen tus tablas? ¿qué es lo que has intentado? ¿con qué errores/dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mvce] para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolví con la siguiente `query`

```
SELECT TOP (1000)
      [MiColumna1],
      COUNT(*) AS RecuentoFilas
FROM [mi_db].[dbo].[mi_tabla]
GROUP BY [MiColumna1]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY [MiColumna1]
```

Obtendremos aquellos valores que se están duplicando en la tabla, en este caso `[MiColumna1]` es la columna que tengo datos duplicados, hacemos un `COUNT(*)` y agrupamos por la misma columna haciendo que cuente todas la filas que sean superior a 1 usando el `HAVING`

Comment: Listo, explicado !